# Refreshing Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am using a main activity to show different fragments. I need to refresh **one of fragment** according to broadcast result. What I mention about is below.

My fragment class:

```
public class ConservationFragment extends Fragment
{
FragmentType fragmentType;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public ConservationFragment()
{
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conservation, container, false);
    try
    {
        this.fragmentType = (FragmentType) getArguments().getSerializable("fragmenttype");
        ArrayList<Message> messageRecords = getMessagesFromDB(fragmentType);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conservationsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mAdapter = new ConversationAdapter(messageRecords, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        return rootView;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("RUNTIME ERROR", "Please check ConversationFragment's onCreateView method.");
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conservation, container, false);
}


public ArrayList<Message> getMessagesFromDB(FragmentType fragmentType)
{
    ..
}
}
```

How I initiate fragments in main activity ;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

//This is our tablayout
private TabLayout tabLayout;

//This is our viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;

ConservationFragment personalFragment;
ConservationFragment blockedFragment;

SmsReceiver receiver;

ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


String[] tabTitle = {"PERSONAL", "BLOCKED"}; //
int[] unreadCount = {1, 2};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    receiver = new SmsReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    try
    {
        setupTabIcons();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {

        }
    });

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    Bundle personalCriterial= new Bundle();
    personalCriterial.putSerializable("fragmenttype",FragmentType.PERSONAL);
    Bundle blockedCriterial= new Bundle();
    blockedCriterial.putSerializable("fragmenttype",FragmentType.BLOCKED);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    personalFragment = new ConservationFragment();
    personalFragment.setArguments(personalCriterial);
    blockedFragment = new ConservationFragment();
    blockedFragment.setArguments(blockedCriterial);

    adapter.addFragment(personalFragment, tabTitle[0]);
    adapter.addFragment(blockedFragment, tabTitle[1]);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupTabIcons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tabTitle.length; i++)
    {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(prepareTabView(i));
    }
}

private View prepareTabView(int pos)
{
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    TextView tv_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    TextView tv_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
    tv_title.setText(tabTitle[pos]);
    return view;
}

public void receiveMessage(Intent intent)
{
    //here I want to refresh one of my fragments. such as personalFragment..
}

}
```

Critical point is here; tab view should not go first tab.(Updatement should be in same fragment)
I am aware of code is so long but I have to show how I initiate objects to lead solutions. Thanks.

Comment: what in the fragment are you trying to refresh? creating a new fragment is expensive, and if you are just trying to update something in the fragment, suggest to follow the VM approach using something like databinding. also, you have a lot of code in onResume that should be in onCreate. each time you pause & resume & repeat, you now have many listeners added to the viewPager and keep resetting values.

Comment: EventBus library will help you to communicate between fragment and activity and it's easy to implement

Comment: Dear @ekeitho ; Unfortunately, I am aware of allocating that you mention but I can not give a solution to update single fragment (personalFragment or blockedFragment).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to update the whole fragment, but only pass some data and refresh textviews or lists, you can always define public methods in fragment and call it from activity.

Example method in fragment:

```
public void updateWithData(String exampleString) {
    myTextView.setText(exampleString);
}
```

Example usage in activity:

```
public void receiveMessage(Intent intent) {
    myFragment.updateWithDate("Example string message");
}
```

This way, you don't need to recreate the whole fragment and you can update only relevant UI elements instead. However, keep in mind that it is up to you to make sure that fragment is created and shown when you will call this update method, otherwise you will get undefined behavior.

PS: It might be a good idea to create something like Updatable interface and implement it in your fragment, so you can reuse this update logic somewhere else in your application. But it's not required and for small scope, public methods should be sufficient enough.